# SUM and COUNT for multiple condition in one query

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL. This is what i am trying.

Table: `h_invoices` sample

| InvNo (AI) | InvCustomer | InvTotal | InvPayment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | Foo | 6750 | 6750 |
| 19 | Bar | 3300 | 3300 |

Table: `h_invdetail` sample

| indID (AI) | invID | ProductID | UnitRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 18 | 1 | 3800 |
| 19 | 18 | 5 | 2950 |

What i want is the count of `ProductA`, `ProductB` and so on based on `ProductID` and the `totalRevenue` which is `sum(InvTotal)`.

What i have tried, for example in case of **InvNo - 18**:

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when h_invdetail.ProductId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ProductA,
    sum(case when h_invdetail.ProductId = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as ProductB,
    sum(case when h_invdetail.ProductId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as ProductC, 
    sum(h_invoices.InvTotal) as REVENUE 
FROM h_invdetail 
LEFT JOIN h_invoices ON h_invdetail.invID = h_invoices.InvNo 
WHERE h_invoices.InvNo = 18
```

I am getting sum as **13500** instead of **6750**. This is just for example, I have to get the Revenue and product distribution for the whole table, but i am getting wrong value for `sum(h_invoices.InvTotal)`. Am i missing something?

Comment: `h_invoices.InvTotal as REVENUE` - this data is on the side "one" and does not need in aggregation.

Comment: As Akina mentioned, use MAX( h_invoices.InvTotal ) because that already represents the aggregation of all the details.

Comment: ummm @DRapp, I want the sum of the InvTotal column of the whole table.. I just considered InvNo 18 for example.. and after that perform some operations like total debt which is (sum of InvTotal)  - (sum of InvPayment).. For the whole table, not particularly for invoice #18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then what you really need is TWO queries wrapped into one.  Your first part to get the total of ALL Invoices, make that a subquery that will return only a single record.  Then a second subquery that is just your invoice #18 which will return a single record, then pull the columns from each.  Since a 1:1 result in each table, you can do without explicit join like

```
select
      PQ1.Revenue,
      PQ2.ProductA,
      PQ2.ProductB,
      PQ2.ProductC
   from
      ( SELECT sum (i.InvTotal) as Revenue 
           FROM h_invoices i ) PQ1,
      ( select
              sum(case when d.ProductId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ProductA,
              sum(case when d.ProductId = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as ProductB,
              sum(case when d.ProductId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as ProductC
           from h_invdetail d
           WHERE d.InvNo = 18 ) PQ2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i am getting the output as expected.